# JTable change view but not change row selection after filter data

Tags: java, jtable, row

When data filtered table row was change view according to result but when I select row then table select always first row of column not filtered row but I want both things filter row and same row selection please solve me problem.

```
jTextField2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
        trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+jTextField2.getText(),0));
    }
}); 


tm = (TableModel)table.getModel();
trs = new TableRowSorter(tm);
table.setRowSorter(trs);
```

Thanks!

Comment: to get the right row, you have to call `int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());`, because the actual model (the data) does not change, only what you can see. so you might see in row 1 the value 5 after filtering, but before it was 1. if you now want to get the value 5 you need to convert it, otherwise you get 1 instead of 5

Comment: where i call modelrow please brief because i used after  table.setRowSorter(trs); but an error occur  (An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:)

Comment: you call it where ever you want to access the data from the selected row. also use `DefaultTableModel` instead of `TableModel`

Comment: when i click on row (mouse event) 
         int index = table.getSelectedRow();
         TableModel model =  (TableModel) table.getModel();
         name = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
          sale.setVisible(true);
          sale.pack();
          sale.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          sale.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          sale.jTextField5.setText(name);
          dispose();
i have use modeRow instead of index but not require results

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER IS FOR FORMATTED CODE PURPOSE

```
int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
name=model.getValueAt(index,0).toString();
sale.setVisible(true);
sale.pack();
sale.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
sale.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
sale.jTextField5.setText(name);
dispose();
```

so this code is not working for you in your mouse event? does the mouse event get triggered? could you edit your question and add more code (if possible all)?